# Matplotlib subscript

Tags: python, matplotlib, subscript

I know that we can produce a single subscript in matplotlib like

```
$r_i$
```

will give me an r with "i" as the subscript.

But I want to generate a subscript with say 3 or 4 letters, like `r_ijk` should give me an r with "ijk" as the subscript.

When I do the above, I only get the first **("i")** to be the subscript, the rest **("j" & "k")** are becoming normal scripts.

Comment: Matplotlib uses [Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/) to typeset the text within `$...$`. [This](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_117.html) is a little help about subscript and superscript. If there are no `{...}` only the first letter or command is used as sub/super-script

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano thank for the info! the {} braces did the trick

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just tried `$r_{ijk}$` and it did the trick! I was previously trying with () braces.

Comment: @mbatchkarov but it does not state clearly that {} braces would solve this trick, but anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: Is this really working for you? I am getting a KeyError!

Comment: Are you using `str.format()`? If you are using that with braces like in `r'$\sigma_{ijk}={0}$'.format(num)` format is taking the contents of the first enclosed braces and since it doesn't know what `ijk` is, it is giving an error (specifically, a KeyError). You need to double braces when you want literal braces.