# Subscript in matplotlib legend using a iteration variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, subscript

I want to use a subscript in a matplotlib legend.

The code looks like:

```
for i in np.arange(10):     
    plt.plot(xdata, ydata, label='$P_i$')
```

This would give me ten times the legend item P_i

I want to read out the value of i for each iteration of the loop, such that I would get a legend like
P_1, P_2, P_3, ...

I already found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322682/matplotlib-subscript) in stackoverflow, but it didn't give me the result I want; it produced subscripts properly, but not with a changing index.

Thank you,
lepakk

Comment: `label=f"P_{i}"`

Comment: Thanks, what an easy solution... You just gotta know it... :)